# Error with Langgraph CRAG implementation with calling a text generation node

Tags: langchain, langgraph

I am trying to build a corrective RAG  application and I am not able to get a generate text with the retrieved documents, I am using Ollama locally to execute this code, there are other nodes as well, the retrieve node functions correctly but the generate node does not

This is what is one of the node of generate

```
    """
    Generate answer

    Args:
        state (dict): The current graph state

    Returns:
        state (dict): New key added to state, generation, that contains generation
    """
    print("---GENERATE---")
    state_dict = state["keys"]
    question = state_dict["question"]
    local = state_dict["local"]
    documents = state_dict["documents"]

    # Prompt
    prompt = hub.pull("rlm/rag-prompt") # Pulls the prompt template from https://smith.langchain.com/hub/rlm/rag-prompt


    # LLM
    if local == "Yes":
        llm = ChatOllama(model="mistral:instruct", temperature=0)
    else:
        pass
    

    #Post-processing
    def format_docs(docs):
        return "\n\n".join([doc.page_content for doc in docs])
    
    #Chain
    rag_chain = prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()

    #Run
    generation = rag_chain.invoke({"context": documents, "questions": question})

    return {"keys": {"documents": documents, "question": question, "generation": generation}}
```

The input I am trying to pass is

```
res1 = generate({'keys': {'documents': [Document(page_content="Memory stream: is a long-term memory module (external database) that records a comprehensive list of agents’ experience in natural language.\n\nEach element is an observation, an event directly provided by the agent.\n- Inter-agent communication can trigger new natural language statements.\n\n\nRetrieval model: surfaces the context to inform the agent’s behavior, according to relevance, recency and importance.\n\nRecency: recent events have higher scores\nImportance: distinguish mundane from core memories. Ask LM directly.\nRelevance: based on how related it is to the current situation / query.\n\n\nReflection mechanism: synthesizes memories into higher level inferences over time and guides the agent’s future behavior. They are higher-level summaries of past events (<- note that this is a bit different from self-reflection above)\n\nPrompt LM with 100 most recent observations and to generate 3 most salient high-level questions given a set of observations/statements. Then ask LM to answer those questions.\n\n\nPlanning & Reacting: translate the reflections and the environment information into actions\n\nPlanning is essentially in order to optimize believability at the moment vs in time.\nPrompt template: {Intro of an agent X}. Here is X's plan today in broad strokes: 1)\nRelationships between agents and observations of one agent by another are all taken into consideration for planning and reacting.\nEnvironment information is present in a tree structure.", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"}),
   Document(page_content="Memory stream: is a long-term memory module (external database) that records a comprehensive list of agents’ experience in natural language.\n\nEach element is an observation, an event directly provided by the agent.\n- Inter-agent communication can trigger new natural language statements.\n\n\nRetrieval model: surfaces the context to inform the agent’s behavior, according to relevance, recency and importance.\n\nRecency: recent events have higher scores\nImportance: distinguish mundane from core memories. Ask LM directly.\nRelevance: based on how related it is to the current situation / query.\n\n\nReflection mechanism: synthesizes memories into higher level inferences over time and guides the agent’s future behavior. They are higher-level summaries of past events (<- note that this is a bit different from self-reflection above)\n\nPrompt LM with 100 most recent observations and to generate 3 most salient high-level questions given a set of observations/statements. Then ask LM to answer those questions.\n\n\nPlanning & Reacting: translate the reflections and the environment information into actions\n\nPlanning is essentially in order to optimize believability at the moment vs in time.\nPrompt template: {Intro of an agent X}. Here is X's plan today in broad strokes: 1)\nRelationships between agents and observations of one agent by another are all taken into consideration for planning and reacting.\nEnvironment information is present in a tree structure.", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"}),
   Document(page_content="Memory stream: is a long-term memory module (external database) that records a comprehensive list of agents’ experience in natural language.\n\nEach element is an observation, an event directly provided by the agent.\n- Inter-agent communication can trigger new natural language statements.\n\n\nRetrieval model: surfaces the context to inform the agent’s behavior, according to relevance, recency and importance.\n\nRecency: recent events have higher scores\nImportance: distinguish mundane from core memories. Ask LM directly.\nRelevance: based on how related it is to the current situation / query.\n\n\nReflection mechanism: synthesizes memories into higher level inferences over time and guides the agent’s future behavior. They are higher-level summaries of past events (<- note that this is a bit different from self-reflection above)\n\nPrompt LM with 100 most recent observations and to generate 3 most salient high-level questions given a set of observations/statements. Then ask LM to answer those questions.\n\n\nPlanning & Reacting: translate the reflections and the environment information into actions\n\nPlanning is essentially in order to optimize believability at the moment vs in time.\nPrompt template: {Intro of an agent X}. Here is X's plan today in broad strokes: 1)\nRelationships between agents and observations of one agent by another are all taken into consideration for planning and reacting.\nEnvironment information is present in a tree structure.", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"}),
   Document(page_content="LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nLil'Log\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nPosts\n\n\n\n\nArchive\n\n\n\n\nSearch\n\n\n\n\nTags\n\n\n\n\nFAQ\n\n\n\n\nemojisearch.app\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n      LLM Powered Autonomous Agents\n    \nDate: June 23, 2023  |  Estimated Reading Time: 31 min  |  Author: Lilian Weng\n\n\n \n\n\nTable of Contents\n\n\n\nAgent System Overview\n\nComponent One: Planning\n\nTask Decomposition\n\nSelf-Reflection\n\n\nComponent Two: Memory\n\nTypes of Memory\n\nMaximum Inner Product Search (MIPS)\n\n\nComponent Three: Tool Use\n\nCase Studies\n\nScientific Discovery Agent\n\nGenerative Agents Simulation\n\nProof-of-Concept Examples\n\n\nChallenges\n\nCitation\n\nReferences\n\n\n\n\n\nBuilding agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview#\nIn a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:\n\nPlanning\n\nSubgoal and decomposition: The agent breaks down large tasks into smaller, manageable subgoals, enabling efficient handling of complex tasks.\nReflection and refinement: The agent can do self-criticism and self-reflection over past actions, learn from mistakes and refine them for future steps, thereby improving the quality of final results.\n\n\nMemory\n\nShort-term memory: I would consider all the in-context learning (See Prompt Engineering) as utilizing short-term memory of the model to learn.\nLong-term memory: This provides the agent with the capability to retain and recall (infinite) information over extended periods, often by leveraging an external vector store and fast retrieval.\n\n\nTool use", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"})],
  'local': 'Yes',
  'question': 'Explain how the different types of agent memory work?'}})
```

Below is the full trace of error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[59], line 1
----> 1 res1 = generate({'keys': {'documents': [Document(page_content="Memory stream: is a long-term memory module (external database) that records a comprehensive list of agents’ experience in natural language.\n\nEach element is an observation, an event directly provided by the agent.\n- Inter-agent communication can trigger new natural language statements.\n\n\nRetrieval model: surfaces the context to inform the agent’s behavior, according to relevance, recency and importance.\n\nRecency: recent events have higher scores\nImportance: distinguish mundane from core memories. Ask LM directly.\nRelevance: based on how related it is to the current situation / query.\n\n\nReflection mechanism: synthesizes memories into higher level inferences over time and guides the agent’s future behavior. They are higher-level summaries of past events (<- note that this is a bit different from self-reflection above)\n\nPrompt LM with 100 most recent observations and to generate 3 most salient high-level questions given a set of observations/statements. Then ask LM to answer those questions.\n\n\nPlanning & Reacting: translate the reflections and the environment information into actions\n\nPlanning is essentially in order to optimize believability at the moment vs in time.\nPrompt template: {Intro of an agent X}. Here is X's plan today in broad strokes: 1)\nRelationships between agents and observations of one agent by another are all taken into consideration for planning and reacting.\nEnvironment information is present in a tree structure.", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"}),
      2    Document(page_content="Memory stream: is a long-term memory module (external database) that records a comprehensive list of agents’ experience in natural language.\n\nEach element is an observation, an event directly provided by the agent.\n- Inter-agent communication can trigger new natural language statements.\n\n\nRetrieval model: surfaces the context to inform the agent’s behavior, according to relevance, recency and importance.\n\nRecency: recent events have higher scores\nImportance: distinguish mundane from core memories. Ask LM directly.\nRelevance: based on how related it is to the current situation / query.\n\n\nReflection mechanism: synthesizes memories into higher level inferences over time and guides the agent’s future behavior. They are higher-level summaries of past events (<- note that this is a bit different from self-reflection above)\n\nPrompt LM with 100 most recent observations and to generate 3 most salient high-level questions given a set of observations/statements. Then ask LM to answer those questions.\n\n\nPlanning & Reacting: translate the reflections and the environment information into actions\n\nPlanning is essentially in order to optimize believability at the moment vs in time.\nPrompt template: {Intro of an agent X}. Here is X's plan today in broad strokes: 1)\nRelationships between agents and observations of one agent by another are all taken into consideration for planning and reacting.\nEnvironment information is present in a tree structure.", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"}),
      3    Document(page_content="Memory stream: is a long-term memory module (external database) that records a comprehensive list of agents’ experience in natural language.\n\nEach element is an observation, an event directly provided by the agent.\n- Inter-agent communication can trigger new natural language statements.\n\n\nRetrieval model: surfaces the context to inform the agent’s behavior, according to relevance, recency and importance.\n\nRecency: recent events have higher scores\nImportance: distinguish mundane from core memories. Ask LM directly.\nRelevance: based on how related it is to the current situation / query.\n\n\nReflection mechanism: synthesizes memories into higher level inferences over time and guides the agent’s future behavior. They are higher-level summaries of past events (<- note that this is a bit different from self-reflection above)\n\nPrompt LM with 100 most recent observations and to generate 3 most salient high-level questions given a set of observations/statements. Then ask LM to answer those questions.\n\n\nPlanning & Reacting: translate the reflections and the environment information into actions\n\nPlanning is essentially in order to optimize believability at the moment vs in time.\nPrompt template: {Intro of an agent X}. Here is X's plan today in broad strokes: 1)\nRelationships between agents and observations of one agent by another are all taken into consideration for planning and reacting.\nEnvironment information is present in a tree structure.", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"}),
      4    Document(page_content="LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nLil'Log\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nPosts\n\n\n\n\nArchive\n\n\n\n\nSearch\n\n\n\n\nTags\n\n\n\n\nFAQ\n\n\n\n\nemojisearch.app\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n      LLM Powered Autonomous Agents\n    \nDate: June 23, 2023  |  Estimated Reading Time: 31 min  |  Author: Lilian Weng\n\n\n \n\n\nTable of Contents\n\n\n\nAgent System Overview\n\nComponent One: Planning\n\nTask Decomposition\n\nSelf-Reflection\n\n\nComponent Two: Memory\n\nTypes of Memory\n\nMaximum Inner Product Search (MIPS)\n\n\nComponent Three: Tool Use\n\nCase Studies\n\nScientific Discovery Agent\n\nGenerative Agents Simulation\n\nProof-of-Concept Examples\n\n\nChallenges\n\nCitation\n\nReferences\n\n\n\n\n\nBuilding agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview#\nIn a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:\n\nPlanning\n\nSubgoal and decomposition: The agent breaks down large tasks into smaller, manageable subgoals, enabling efficient handling of complex tasks.\nReflection and refinement: The agent can do self-criticism and self-reflection over past actions, learn from mistakes and refine them for future steps, thereby improving the quality of final results.\n\n\nMemory\n\nShort-term memory: I would consider all the in-context learning (See Prompt Engineering) as utilizing short-term memory of the model to learn.\nLong-term memory: This provides the agent with the capability to retain and recall (infinite) information over extended periods, often by leveraging an external vector store and fast retrieval.\n\n\nTool use", metadata={'description': 'Building agents with LLM (large language model) as its core controller is a cool concept. Several proof-of-concepts demos, such as AutoGPT, GPT-Engineer and BabyAGI, serve as inspiring examples. The potentiality of LLM extends beyond generating well-written copies, stories, essays and programs; it can be framed as a powerful general problem solver.\nAgent System Overview In a LLM-powered autonomous agent system, LLM functions as the agent’s brain, complemented by several key components:', 'language': 'en', 'source': 'https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2023-06-23-agent/', 'title': "LLM Powered Autonomous Agents | Lil'Log"})],
      5   'local': 'Yes',
      6   'question': 'Explain how the different types of agent memory work?'}})
      8 res1

Cell In[58], line 43
     40     return "\n\n".join([doc.page_content for doc in docs])
     42 #Chain
---> 43 rag_chain = prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()
     45 #Run
     46 generation = rag_chain.invoke({"context": documents, "questions": question})

File ~/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py:433, in Runnable.__ror__(self, other)
    423 def __ror__(
    424     self,
    425     other: Union[
   (...)
    430     ],
    431 ) -> RunnableSerializable[Other, Output]:
...
-> 4366     if isinstance(thing, Runnable):
   4367         return thing
   4368     elif inspect.isasyncgenfunction(thing) or inspect.isgeneratorfunction(thing):

TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'str'>
```

please suggest what is that I am missing